# Trying to put input from a textfield in the console, page just goes blank

Tags: javascript, html, input, textfield

I'm trying to write a simple program.  I write text in a textfeild, click submit, and it shows up in the console.  Sounds simple, right?  I thought so too.  Unfortunately, when I click submit, the page just goes blank.  No errors, it just goes blank.  Why is this happening? Even changing the submit button to a regular, generic button did not work.

Here is my code:

```js
function write(){
  var graffiti = document.getElementById("graffiti").value; 
  console.log(graffiti);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="graffiti.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" id="graffiti"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="write()">
  </body>
</html>
```

What's the deal?

Comment: try adding e.preventDefault() maybe?

Comment: how and where exactly what I put it?

Comment: in the first line in write() method

Comment: `function write(e) {}` and in the first line add `e.preventDefault()`;

Comment: Okay, that's what I did.  Or do I need to put the "e" in the html too?

Comment: That doesn't work.  That causes an error.  Sorry, I should have tried that before asking but I'm slightly drunk.

Comment: can you provide a working example on plunker / codepen / codesandbox?

Comment: a "not working" example, hahahah

Comment: I don't know how to use any of those sites

Answer (score 1):

try the following way

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head> </head>
  <body>
      <input type="text" id="graffiti" /><br />
      <input id="myBtn" type="submit" value="submit" />

    <script>
        function write() {
          var graffiti = document.getElementById("graffiti").value;
          console.log(graffiti);
        }

        document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", write);
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Theory of because this example does not work [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53422883/trying-to-put-input-from-a-textfield-in-the-console-page-just-goes-blank)

> It is not working by the name the function that we are passing on the onclick.
>   I think it brings you conflict with the glocal definition of document.write [document.write](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_write.asp)

Rename write() to myFunction().

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head> </head>
  <body>
        <input type="text" id="graffiti"><br>
        <input id="dasd" type="submit" value="submit" onclick="myFunction()">

    <script>
        function myFunction($event){
            var graffiti = document.getElementById("graffiti").value;
            console.log(graffiti);        
        }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I leave an interesting link

- [Event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)
- [addEventListener vs onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick)

Comment: That worked, thank you.  But I still wish I knew why the other one didn't.

Comment: Crazy!! It's not working the way you're doing by the name of the function when you're calling on the onclick event

I think it brings you conflict with the glocal definition of document.write https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_write.asp

rename write() to myFunction()